# Special symbols in PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, character-encoding, fpdf

Im developing a PDF generation script with PHP, using FPDF library, its all fine for text and images, but when I put corrency symbols like Pound or Euro, it is giving some special symbols instead, I could solver the same in normal pages by setting character encoding of the webpage, but not sure how to set character encoding for a PDF document.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for the generation script?

Answer (score 0):

You are running into encoding - decoding issues.. Add this line on top of your script.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

followed by your FDPF generation code.